# What does "quick with his hands" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), press agent Sidney assures the
unimpressed Evans that he will provide Temple with proper publicity build
for his performance:

> Temple: Al makes all the deals, doc. I can't —
>
> Sidney: I don't like a fella that's **quick with his hands**. You know,
> Temple, you've been three passes behind for the last  20 years.

What does "quick with his hands" mean?

Comment: Metaphor: dextrous in business dealings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first meaning is the literal "deft, agile" in the domain of handiwork, whether it's dealing cards or dribbling a basketball or turning a Rubik's cube.

But the secondary meaning, and the one surely intended here, is that such a person is capable of *sleight of hand* — think of a shyster running a shell game. Their quickness means they can get away with a bit of cheating or deception or misdirection. If they shuffle a figurative deck of cards, you don't know whether they slipped in a joker or strategically placed the ace.

Without context, I read the rest of Sidney's line as suggesting that Al has been cheating Temple in exactly this way throughout the 20 years that he's been "making all the deals".